# How to solve error message: no such column: auctions_auction.image_url

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm creating an aunction website where users will submit a form with the link to an image when creating a new listing. This link/url will then be converted and displayed as an image on the website. I keep getting this error when I upload the details of the form including the link to the image -

""OperationalError at /create/

no such column: auctions_auction.image_url.""

How can I clear this error?

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import AuctionForm


def create_listing(request):
    form = AuctionForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuctionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = AuctionForm()
    context = {'form': form}  
    return render(request, 'auctions/create-listing.html', context)
```

FORMS.PY

```
from .models import Auction
from django import forms
from django.forms import fields

class AuctionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Auction
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'current_bid', 'image_url']
```

MODELS.PY

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files import File
from urllib.request import urlopen
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


class Auction(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField()
    current_bid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    users_bid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    image_upload = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    image_url = models.URLField(verbose_name="URL", max_length=255, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image_url and not self.image_upload:
            img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
            img_temp.write(urlopen(self.image_url).read())
            img_temp.flush()
            self.image_upload.save(f"image_{self.pk}", File(img_temp))
        super(self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

HTML

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("create/", views.create_listing, name="create_listing")
]

if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                              document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to migrate your model changes into the database. This might work:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thank you, I did that. I am currently having this error "TypeError at /create/
super() argument 1 must be type, not Auction". Do you know what could be causing this please? @NixonSparrow

Comment: Maybe adding your class name will help: `super(Auction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Hello @NixonSparrow, I tried this and unfortunately I'm getting this error "IntegrityError at /create/
NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_auction.users_bid"

Comment: It is because you have created before Auction object with `users_bid = None`, and your model forbids such possibility. You have do one of the following: 1. Add `default=0` to `users_bid` field, or 2. Set users_bid of all Auction objects in db to something and remember to never create object without it.